# Ruby's Parsing of iso8601 dates seems broken

Tags: ruby, date, iso8601

I'm parsing dates from an external source (which are required to be in iso8601 format) and running into a strange scenario.

```
require 'date'
Date.iso8601('2000-05-01') #<Date: 2000-05-01 ((2451666j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
Date.iso8601('200-05-01')  #<Date: 2100-05-01 ((2488190j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
Date.iso8601('20-05-01')   #<Date: 2020-05-01 ((2458971j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

I would expect the last 2 calls to blow up with invalid argument exceptions, because the dates are not in the iso8601 format.  Is this a bug in Ruby?

```
ruby --version
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

Comment: Why are they invalid?

Comment: Maybe Ruby just knew people where going to try to break it, so it built functions to stop it from being broken? ;)

Comment: @sawa ISO-8601 requires four-digit years

Comment: @WayneConrad ISO 8601 recommends four-digit years, but not require it.

Comment: @sawa Do you have a source for "does not require [four-digit years]"?  The ISO 8601 standard is "secret" (it's expensive payware), but every public source I find, starting with Wikipedia, mandates a four-digit year.

Comment: @WayneConrad For example, [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) mentions that "ISO 8601 ... allows the century to be omitted from years". Or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years) says "ISO 8601 prescribes, as a minimum, a four-digit year [YYYY] to avoid the year 2000 problem."

Comment: @WayneConrad and it also [cites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#cite_note-11) " ISO 8601:2004(E). ISO. 2004-12-01. 3.5 Expansion ... By mutual agreement of the partners in information interchange, it is permitted to expand the component identifying the calendar year, which is otherwise limited to four digits. This enables reference to dates and times in calendar years outside the range supported by complete representations, i.e. before the start of the year [0000] or after the end of the year [9999]."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-iso8601):

> Creates a new Date object by parsing from a string according to some typical ISO 8601 formats.

```
Date.iso8601('2001-02-03')        #=> #<Date: 2001-02-03 ...>
Date.iso8601('20010203')          #=> #<Date: 2001-02-03 ...>
Date.iso8601('2001-W05-6')        #=> #<Date: 2001-02-03 ...>
```

Not really sure what "typical ISO 8601 formats" mean, as there should really be only one. I wouldn't say it's a bug though.

If you want strict parsing, then I'd look at [`Date#strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime).

Comment: I'm not quite in agreement on it being 'not a bug'.  If the Ruby team tasked you to implement Date.iso8601 would you write 2 unit tests that check that '2001-02-03' is Feb 3 2001, but '200-02-03' is Feb 3 2100??